# Is it a better way to do parallel programming that this?

Tags: go, parallel-processing, channel

I made this script for getting the follower count of "influencers" from instagram

the "runtime" number I am getting from it is between 550-750ms. 
It is not that bad, but I am wondering whether it could be better or not (as I am a golang noob - learning it 3 weeks only)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type user struct {
    User userData `json:"user"`
}

type userData struct {
    Followers count `json:"followed_by"`
}

type count struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
}

func getFollowerCount(in <-chan string) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for un := range in {
            URL := "https://www.instagram.com/" + un + "/?__a=1"
            resp, err := http.Get(URL)
            if err != nil {
                // handle error
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            var u user
            err = json.Unmarshal(body, &u)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            // return u.User.Followers.Count
            out <- u.User.Followers.Count
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int)
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func gen(users ...string) <-chan string {
    out := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for _, u := range users {
            out <- u
        }
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("STARTING UP")
    usrs := []string{"kanywest", "kimkardashian", "groovyq", "kendricklamar", "barackobama", "asaprocky", "champagnepapi", "eminem", "drdre", "g_eazy", "skrillex"}
    in := gen(usrs...)
    d1 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d2 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d3 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d4 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d5 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d6 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d7 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d8 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d9 := getFollowerCount(in)
    d10 := getFollowerCount(in)

    for d := range merge(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10) {
        fmt.Println(d)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Println("runtime", elapsed)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Go, happy learning.

You're doing good, you can improve your program many ways (such as json decoder, less no of chan, etc). Following is one of the approach. Execution time is between 352-446ms (take it with grain of salt, since network call is involved in your code. Might vary based on server response time).

Your updated code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type user struct {
    User userData `json:"user"`
}

type userData struct {
    Followers count `json:"followed_by"`
}

type count struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
}

func getFollowerCount(username string, result chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    reqURL := "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1"
    resp, err := http.Get(reqURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var u user
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&u); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    result <- u.User.Followers.Count
}

func execute(users []string, result chan<- int) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, username := range users {
        wg.Add(1)
        go getFollowerCount(username, result, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    result <- -1
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("STARTING UP")
    usrs := []string{"kanywest", "kimkardashian", "groovyq", "kendricklamar", "barackobama", "asaprocky", "champagnepapi", "eminem", "drdre", "g_eazy", "skrillex"}

    result := make(chan int)
    go execute(usrs, result)

    for v := range result {
        if v == -1 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("runtime:", elapsed)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with jeevatkm, there are numerous way to implement your task and improve it. Some notes:

1. Separate the function that actually do the job (i.e. fetch result from remote service) and the function which is responsible for coordinating all the jobs.
2. It is a good practice to propagate an `error`to the caller instead of consumes (handles) it in a function to be called.
3. Since the jobs are done in *parallel*, the result could be returned in undetermined order. Thus, besides follower count, result should contains other related information(s).

The following implementation may be one alternative:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type user struct {
    User userData `json:"user"`
}

type userData struct {
    Followers count `json:"followed_by"`
}

type count struct {
    Count int `json:"count"`
}

//Wrap username, count, and error. See (3) above.
type follower struct {
    Username string
    Count    int
    Error    error
}

//GetFollowerCountFunc is a function for
//fetching follower count of a specific user.
type GetFollowerCountFunc func(string) (int, error)

//Mockup function for test
func mockGetFollowerCountFor(userName string) (int, error) {
    if len(userName) < 9 {
        return -1, errors.New("mocking error in get follower count")
    }
    return 10, nil
}

//Fetch result from remote service. See (1) above.
func getFollowerCountFor(userName string) (int, error) {
    URL := "https://www.instagram.com/" + userName + "/?__a=1"
    resp, err := http.Get(URL)
    if err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    var u user
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&u); err != nil {
        return -1, err
    }
    return u.User.Followers.Count, nil
}

//Function that coordinates/distributes the jobs. See (1), (2) above.
func getFollowersAsync(users []string, fn GetFollowerCountFunc) <-chan follower {
    //allocate channels for storing result
    //number of allocated channels define the maximum *parallel* worker
    followers := make(chan follower, len(users))
    //The following is also valid
    //followers := make(chan follower, 5)

    //Do the job distribution in goroutine (Asynchronously)
    go func() {
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(len(users))
        for _, u := range users {
            //Run a *parallel* worker
            go func(uid string) {
                cnt, err := fn(uid)
                if err != nil {
                    followers <- follower{uid, -1, err}
                } else {
                    followers <- follower{uid, cnt, nil}
                }
                wg.Done()
            }(u)
        }
        //wait all workers finish
        wg.Wait()

        //close the channels so the `for ... range` will exit gracefully
        close(followers)
    }()

    //This function will returns immediately
    return followers
}

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("STARTING UP")
    usrs := []string{"kanywest", "kimkardashian", "groovyq", "kendricklamar", "barackobama", "asaprocky", "champagnepapi", "eminem", "drdre", "g_eazy", "skrillex"}

    results := getFollowersAsync(usrs, getFollowerCountFor)
    //For TESTING:
    //results := getFollowersAsync(usrs, mockGetFollowerCountFor)
    for r := range results {
        if r.Error != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error for user '%s' => %v", r.Username, r.Error)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %d\n", r.Username, r.Count)
        }
    }

    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("runtime", elapsed)
}
```